# Cells won't update until externally referred workbook is opened

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook named *amazonExpenses.xlsx* that contains data to be shared among many workbooks.
I have a workbook named *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm* that references data externally from the *amazonExpenses.xlsx* workbook.

Referencing data from the *amazonExpenses.xlsx* workbook in vlookup function goes well.

```
=VLOOKUP(A9,'D:\[AmazonExpenses.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$9:$C$15,3,FALSE)
```

This works and displays data when I open the *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm* workbook.
This works when the *amazonExpenses.xlsx* file is closed and open.

But when I pass data reference from *amazonExpenses.xlsx* to a VBA function in *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm* problem starts.

```
=findInBetween(E7,'D:\[AmazonExpenses.xlsx]Sheet1'!$J$2:$J$24,'D:\[AmazonExpenses.xlsx]Sheet1'!$K$2:$K$24,'D:\[AmazonExpenses.xlsx]Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$24)
```

`findInBetween` is my custom VBA function which is called in cell D9 of *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm*

```vb
Public Function findInBetween(valueToFind As Variant, ByRef lowBound As Range, ByRef upperBound As Range, ByRef resultArr As Range) As Variant
Dim ans As Variant: ans = 0
For i = 0 To lowBound.Count
    If valueToFind >= lowBound(i) And valueToFind <= upperBound(i) Then
        ans = resultArr(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
findInBetween = ans

End Function
```

When I open *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm* workbook I get *#VALUE!* in cell D9.

Passing reference from other workbook in VBA function is not working.
But as soon as I open *amazonExpenses.xlsx* when *tapeCalcForAmazon.xlsm* is already open the function works and automatically updates all cells with data.

I don't want to open the *amazonExpenses.xlsx* file all the time. It should work with this file closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will open the data workbook automatically and hide, it will update any data in your workbook that you are currently working in. Catch is you won't be able to have both open to edit at the same time. Place this code in "ThisWorkbook" in the Project Explorer and change the filename to your file path.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
                                
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\amazonExpenses.xlsx" 
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False   
    
End Sub
```